# Can I have multiple versions deployed on openshift?

Tags: google-app-engine, openshift, paas

For a research project I am comparing PaaS providers. I'm however not sure about the following. On App Engine I can have multiple live versions of my application. If I have a new version and I deploy it I can reach it on a non-default url like: versionX.myapp.appspot.com. I can use that url to test it while running on the PaaS. Once I'm happy with the result I will change the default version and my visitors will also see the changes.

I am wondering if Openshift has something simular? Only thing I found so far is that it deploys on git push and if it fails to build it will leave the old version live. This of course still leaves a risk for functional errors. If I then still have to install a test-server locally I am still doing system administration and it would be nice if this can be prevented.

How is this best resolved when using openshift?

Edit: I did found this article: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/release-management-in-the-cloud

Is that the way to or are there other common ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to re-create the google functionality would be to run a dev/qa instance on a separate gear and add those git repositories as remotes to your local git working copy, then you can git push to any environment for testing before you deploy to production.

Comment: So you are confirming what I found in the mentioned blog. Thanks for your input!